# Parsing JSON/YAML as Network.HTTP.Base.Request

Tags: json, haskell, yaml

I'm trying to parse a YAML chunk and create a Request instance from it.
So basically I have the following (implementations of `FromJSON URI`, `FromJSON RequestMethod` and `FromJSON Header` are omitted for brevity):

```
...
instance FromJSON (Request r) where
  parseJSON (Object v) = Request <$>
    v .: "uri" <*>
    v .: "method" <*>
    v .: "headers" <*>
    v .: "body"
```

Trying to compile (using GHC) this code produces:

```
    No instance for (FromJSON r)
      arising from a use of `.:'
    In the second argument of `(<*>)', namely `v .: "body"'
    In the expression:
      Request <$> v .: "uri" <*> v .: "method" <*> v .: "headers"
      <*> v .: "body"
    In an equation for `parseJSON':
        parseJSON (Object v)
          = Request <$> v .: "uri" <*> v .: "method" <*> v .: "headers"
            <*> v .: "body"
```

I feel it's a newbie question (and that's who I am), but apparently GHC cannot infer the type for the request body (which appears to be polymorphic) and I'm lacking the skills for handling this. Although I managed to "pacify" the compiler by replacing the instance declaration with:

```
instance FromJSON (Request Text) where
...
```

and adding `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}` option, but I'm somehow sure it's wrong.
So, how do I properly parse this (and similar cases)?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried adding a `FromJSON` constraint to your instance? E.g. `instance FromJSON r => FromJSON (Request r)`

Comment: It worked! This makes sense, and the code got compiled. I tried testing it:

    tj :: Maybe (Request a)
    tj = decode "{uri: 'http://example.com/', method: GET, headers: [], body: 'hello'}"

...but got error:

    No instance for (FromJSON a)
      arising from a use of `decode'
    In the expression:
      decode
        "{uri: 'http://example.com/', method: GET, headers: [], body: 'hello'}"
    In an equation for `tj':
        tj
          = decode
              "{uri: 'http://example.com/', method: GET, headers: [], body: 'hello'}"


I wonder if I'm on the right track?

Comment: Updated the testing function declaration to:

`tj :: FromJSON a => Maybe (Request a)`

Now it compiles, but outputs:


    Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
      (FromJSON a0) arising from a use of `tj'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the expression: tj
    In an equation for `it': it = tj

When I try to call "tj". I'm afraid, this is a wrong way to go.

Comment: That's probably fine. It just needs to be able to infer from the context what the `a` type needs to be. You can do this either by adding a type annotation where you're using it, or by restricting the type to something like `tj :: Maybe (Request Text)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @hammar, the answer boils down to the 2 following points:

1) To be able to join the computation, "r" (which refers to the request body) in the instance declaration has to be restricted to "FromJSON" class.

```
instance FromJSON r => FromJSON (Request r) where
  parseJSON (Object v) = Request <$>
    v .: "uri" <*>
    v .: "method" <*>
    v .: "headers" <*>
    v .: "body"
```

2) and, when the parser is used, it must be explicitly notified of the body type it is to handle:

```
testJSON :: Maybe (Request Text)
testJSON = decode "{uri: 'http://example.com/', method: GET, headers: [], body: 'hello'}"
```

I'm not sure how obvious that was, but GHC could've inferred the class restriction on its own, I guess. Not yet, perhaps.